# "Last Seen" timestamps are out of date in careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Whatever process updates the [last-seen timestamps](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/haren#section-1004) in careers appears to be broken:
[image]

I checked multiple people.

Comment: will i get more attention if I use freehand circles?

Comment: @Michael:  This'll get fixed sometime today.

Comment: We didn't account for relativity in our calculations

Comment: Rep is out of date as well.

Comment: @Matt yep, same bug

Comment: @Jason @Matt Sherman ping

Comment: @Robin these are working for me (since early March)...not for you?

Comment: @Michael Ah, it's working for me now - wasn't working at the weekend.